# Do Visual Studio Reference gets compiled after build?

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2019

Do Visual Studio Reference gets compiled after build?

If not, do they have to be the same directory that the app is looking for?

For example, I have a reference in `C:/somefolder/someref.dll`, when I build it and pass it on someone's device, do they need to have the reference on the same exact folder or is that not needed (it gets compiled along with the app)

I'm building a C# class library app/plugin then upon adding a reference, PDFSharp to be specific, it tells me `System.IO.FIlenotfound Exception` even though the nuget package is added

Comment: Reference, if you are referencing a project. Then your build may cause compilation. system.IO.FIlenotfound Exception is a classic missing file error. Generally, you can set the dll file as copy if new, and then change the reference address to the output directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a class project, you can export referenced external DLLs to the output directory.
However, the external DLL must also be present in the location where the startup project's executable file is located.
Therefore, when a class project is referenced by an executable project, you must also reference the external DLLs referenced by the class project and export them to the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your app, by default the PDFSharp's dll should be in the same folder as the exe (in bin/Debug/ or bin/Release).

Make sure PDFSharp's dll is in the same directory as the executable when you distribute it. If you're using .NET 5 or above you can publish a [single file app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)

Comment: Thank you!, but the thing is Im developing a class library, not an exe base file. So the output of my project is also *.dll. Now it keeps having the error System.IO.FIlenotfound Exception, though I tried it and it works with an EXE base app

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, turns out the app that I was creating a plug-in into, has a "Dependencies" folder in it. I put the APIs there and it worked!